Animated 70s-80s movie based on the 20,000 leagues under the sea
As I remember this animated movie aired for TV only, and not a general VHS release.  It wasn't originally English, though I saw a dub of it, more about it's country of origin I can't remember or didn't know.  It was approximately in the 70-80s time period, and it was loosely based on the 20,000 leagues under the sea plot.  The main parts I remember being similar was a Captain Nemo on a Nautilus submarine that used absurdly advanced sci-fi features, the underwater battles looked more like a space war.
The underwater submarine battles had dozens of mini-subs launched aircraft carrier style along with torpedoes, and I think laser broadsides or something, in some kind of space / surface naval styled underwater fight.
The plot opened with the main characters on the surface in a city under attack, I can't remember what precisely happened here.  Eventually they end up on Captain Nemo's Nautilus where they're taken on his journey to an underwater super civilization, I'm not sure if it's specifically called Atlantis.
Again the majority of what I remember from the middle of the film is a series of underwater sea battles that looks more like Jules Verne inspired space battles with anime mini-subs and torpedoes / lasers.  The major plot point being the trip to this underwater civilization / Atlantis to stop the war or apocalypse, I can't recall precisely.
The film ends after what I think was some sort of heroic sacrifice and the main characters, excluding Nemo, are unconscious back on the surface in a mini-sub, shipwrecked on an island style.  After what was, or nearly was, the end of the world the ending was left up to the watcher's imagination.  The ending scene cuts without them waking up, with sounds and scene lighting giving the impression of a quiet and peaceful island or sea side location.

It does not match the period you are mentioning, but you might be interested by this other animated series inspired by the works of Jules Verne : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nadia:_The_Secret_of_Blue_Water

This is likely The Return of Captain Nemo.  It was an aborted 1970s American TV series recut into a movie. The Nautilus has lasers and one episode involves visiting Atlantis.  

You are talking about the animated version of 20,000 Leagues Under the Sea (1985 film).

20,000 Leagues Under the Sea is a 1985 Australian made-for-television animated film from Burbank Films Australia. The film is based on Jules Verne's classic novel, Twenty Thousand Leagues Under the Sea, and was adapted by Stephen MacLean.

And the ending, very similar to the ending you described:

The three companions try unsuccessfully to bring Nemo to reason, but he determined even at the risk of his life. Wanting no part in the calamity, the three men take a chance to escape in a rowboat, and wanting to warn the to-be-victimized ship, are thrown ashore by the ocean waves. Finding rest and shelter on an unhabited island, the professor is happy to have kept his journal safe, so he may tell the world of their adventures. No one learns about the fate of the Nautilus and Captain Nemo, who may have perished or still be alive seeking revenge on mankind.


No, that's not it, I've looked at that film and it's not the one I'm looking for.  It was a modern era setting film, not an older colonial era setting.  Too pirates of the carribean not enough war of the worlds.  Actually, I'd say the setting could possibly be called near future, as the cities were modern and the submarines were like you'd expect from anime starships, kind of like an aquatic themed Gundam.
